# How to load configuration dynamically in Next.js deployed app?

Tags: next.js

I want to have dynamic configuration for my Next.js project.

I want to be able to change it after Next.js is built and deployed.

Right now I'm using `.env` and `.env.production` which are part of `dotenv` repo. But it seems that Next.js or `dotenv` compile the content and there is no way to change them dynamically.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't change .env after building and deploying.** *But a workaround is always there.*

Put a JSON file separated from the project and host in the server. Read the JSON file from that server and use that variable in the configuration. But there is a security issue if you put secrets and credentials in that JSON. for that, you can write a simple node project with returning JSON configuration using API. Use a token key to access that API. Put this token secret in that node project. So, changing those variables in that node or JSON project will be more cost-effective than rebuilding and deploying again the whole project.

**or simply put those configuration in database.**